# D3 force graph rendering nodes and links

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, z-index, data-visualization

I am having a problem with my force graph which I have used d3 to create.  I am dynamically adding to the nodes and links array with data I retrieve using d3.json.  My problem comes after the initial rendering and I add more nodes and links to their respective arrays.  The links that are added have been rendered "on-top" of the node.  Unfortunately my nodes consist of images so the link is covering part of that image.  The solution I have come up with is to select everything (nodes and links) inside my svg container and remove them on each update() call and re-enter each element again.  This seems like an inefficient way to go about it.  I have tampered with z-index but to no avail.  Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Use the `insert()` method when adding the links –– instead of `append()` (which you'd continue to use for the nodes).

Comment: I have tried append and insert, both don't make a difference.  I know the problem is I am using an identity function with in .data() to recognize nodes and links that already exist.  Since these already exist the new ones get "appended or inserted" which, since they were created after the originals, they are rendered on top.  I just don't know a work around for this problem except to select all nodes and links and remove them before rendering again.

Comment: I don't see why `insert()` doesn't work -- despite your explanation that you're adding new nodes over time with-or-without the identity function for `data()` keys. I created an answer with code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you always PREpend any link (i.e. add the links to the container before any of the nodes), there will never be a link overlapping a node. You do that with `insert()`, which will prepend as long as you specify a selector matching the nodes you want to keep in on top:

```
forceContainer.selectAll('.node').data(force.nodes())
forceContainer.enter()
  .append('div')
  .attr('class', 'node')

forceContainer.selectAll('.link').data(force.links())
forceContainer.enter()
  .insert('div', '.node') // Inserts link before any of the existing nodes
```

Comment: After re-reading the API and taking into consideration what you said, I got it working.  I ended up adding .insert("line", "image") to the links enter().  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The second argument of .insert fixed it for me too.  I used .insert("line", ":first-child")